# Python - how to install attributes

Tags: python

I'm doing exercise, a simple one.
At the print statement, I want to add the attribute of "title," but seems it doesn't exist in python or doesn't get recognized

```
players = ['messi', 'maradona', 'pele', 'ronaldo', 'rivaldo', 'puyol', 'ramos']
print("Here are the first players on my team:")
for player in players:
    print(players)
```

Comment: the title doesn't appear as an option after the DOT :(
How do I solve it or add these attributes??

Comment: You have a list of strings. What `title` attribute are you talking about?

Comment: It just doesn't exist... You may want to check OOP here:https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html, also what's title supposed to do?

Comment: Or maybe you meant to do `print(player.title())`

Comment: Or maybe you are asking about code completion which all depends on your IDE/editor.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel - thank you for replying - I just realized that because I'm looping on individual element {string} I need to pull the title function on 1 string - the title works only for one element in the string or in my case on 1 element in each irritation  and not several which didn't give me the title completion I wanted   

the title attribute just capitalized the the first letter in the element

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, be sure to operate on `player`, and not `players`

It is not clear from your question, but if you are trying to capitalize each player's name, then this will work:

```
players = ['messi', 'maradona', 'pele', 'ronaldo', 'rivaldo', 'puyol', 'ramos']
print("Here are the first players on my team:")
for player in players:
    print(player.title())
```

title() is a string function which is  applied to a string as shown above.

Comment: Thank for the tip - I was finally able to pull this off  - also was able to to it in a list comprehension and also with the strong understanding for this function  

layers = ['messi', 'maradona', 'pele', 'ronaldo', 'rivaldo', 'puyol', 'ramos']
print(f"Here are the first players on my team:")
team = []
for player in players:
    team.append(player.title())
print(', '.join(team))

players = ['messi', 'maradona', 'pele', 'ronaldo', 'rivaldo', 'puyol', 'ramos']
for value in players[:3]:
    print(f" {value.title()}")

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys thank you for helping me here any way for other beginners to follow

below the resolution to my issue:

```
layers = ['messi', 'maradona', 'pele', 'ronaldo', 'rivaldo', 'puyol', 'ramos']
print(f"Here are the first players on my team:")
team = []
for player in players:
    team.append(player.title())
print(', '.join(team))

players = ['messi', 'maradona', 'pele', 'ronaldo', 'rivaldo', 'puyol', 'ramos']
for value in players[:3]:
    print(f" {value.title()}")
```